# 1>file.log 2>&1 and 1>file.log 2>file.log

Tags: bash

Is there a difference between these two bash commands?

```
$ some_command 1>file.log 2>&1
```

and

```
$ some_command 1>file.log 2>file.log
```

Answer (score 4):

This command:

```
some_command 1>file.log 2>file.log
```

Is not correct way of redirecting stdout and stderr.

If you have `noclobber` option set using: `set -o noclobber`, It will in fact cause this error:

```
-bash: file.log : cannot overwrite existing file
```

However if you turn off `noclobber` option using: `set +C` then

```
some_command 1>file.log 2>file.log
```

will not generate above error though it is much better to use

```
some_command 1>file.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Is 
$ some_command 1>file.log 2>&1  
the same as 
$ some_command 2>&1 1>file.log 
?

Comment: you can however do some_command 1>file_out.log 2>file_err.log

Comment: Technically, `noclobber` must be set to get that error. :-) I.e., `set -o noclobber`.

Comment: @ooga is right, there's nothing wrong with `1>a 2>a`. However, one redirection will override the other.

Comment: @Jalil Those are not the same. `some_command 2>&1 1>file.log` will first make stderr a copy of stdout, and *then* stdout will be redirected to the file.

Comment: @ooga can you give me an example?

Comment: @Jalil: No `some_command 1>file.log 2>&1` **is not same as** `some_command 2>&1 1>file.log` as these directives are processed from left to right.

Comment: In fact `some_command 2>&1 1>file.log` will not redirect error at all to file.

Comment: @anubhava: yes, that left-to-right handling means that the first `2>&1` sends stderr to (the current) stdout; then—now that stderr captures where stdout used to go—`1>file.log` redirects stdout to `file.log`.  For various good reasons, however, `prog1 2>&1 | prog2` creates the pipe first, so that in this case stderr goes down the pipe as well.  The various shells' redirection tricks take some getting used to. :-)

Comment: @torek: Thanks for correcting me. Yes indeed redirection is one of the most intriguing feature I have found in shell programming.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a difference.

```
bash$ (echo foo; echo bar 1>&2) 1>test.out 2>&1
bash$ cat test.out
foo
bar
bash$ (echo foo; echo bar 1>&2) 1>test.out 2>test.out
bash$ cat test.out
bar
bash$
```

As [anubhava notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097888/1256452), if you have `noclobber` set, the second variant does not even run at all (even if you remove the `test.out` file first).  But if this option is unset, as in my example here, what bash does here is open the file twice, rather than opening it once and then using a `dup` system call.

The key difference, in this case, is that a `dup`-ed file descriptor *shares its seek offset* with its original, while a separate `open` does not.  Thus:

- In the first `test.out` example above, stdout (descriptor 1) and stderr (descriptor 2) share the seek offset, which is initially zero.  The `echo foo` command runs, sending its output to its stdout, which is going to the file at offset 0, and writes four bytes including the newline.  This bumps the offset up to 4.  The `echo bar` command then runs, sending its output to stderr,<sup>1</sup> which is going to the file at offset 4—remember, the offset is *shared*—and writes the `bar` and newline to the file.  (The offset is then bumped to 8, but nothing else uses the file, so it gets closed and the offset is discarded.)
- In the second `test.out` example, however, stdout and stderr have separate seek offsets.  Both are opened to `test.out` at offset 0.  The `echo foo` command runs, writing `foo` and a newline to stdout and updating the offset to 4.  Then the `echo bar` command runs, writing `bar` and a newline to stderr, but *at offset 0 again*, overwriting the previous string.  (As before, the offset bumps up, to 4 this time, but everything is done and the two descriptors get closed, discarding the offsets.)

This is why the first test winds up with two lines in the file, but the second test winds up with just one.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the `echo bar` writes to its stdout too, but we use `1>&2` to get stderr (descriptor 2) `dup`ed over to stdout (descriptor 1).  As before, this `dup` causes the offset to get shared.  Note that the `dup` redirection continues only for the duration of the `echo bar` command, after which everything reverts.  This reversion is why we must parenthesize the two `echo` commands in the test itself, so that the outer redirections to `test.out` persist across *both* `echo` invocations.  (Technically, we redirect the descriptors of a `fork`-ed sub-shell that runs the two `echo` commands.)